# Update Large Table

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have these two tables:

```
user_profile:
user_profile_id_int int primary key 
user_profile_id varchar

user_activity:
user_profile_id_int int key
user_profile_id varchar
```

both fields in user_profile are ok but I don't have the user_profile_id_int from user_activity and I want to update it using the map I have in user_profile. I wrote a query like this:

```
update user_activity a
set user_profile_id_int =
(select user_profile_id_int from user_profile b
where a.user_profile_id = b.user_profile_id);
```

It was running on a really strong server for 1 day and I stopped it. But to record has been updated.

So 2 questions here:

1. Is there a better and faster way to do this?
2. Is this way ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Answer to question 1**

This should do it for you

```
UPDATE user_activity a
INNER JOIN user_profile b 
USING (user_profile_id)
SET a.user_profile_id_int = b.user_profile_id_int;
```

This will work in MySQL. If you are not used to that JOIN syntax, do this:

```
UPDATE user_activity a
INNER JOIN user_profile b 
ON a.user_profile_id = b.user_profile_id
SET a.user_profile_id_int = b.user_profile_id_int;
```

Both should work.

### **Answer to question 2**

Your query, in theory, works. However, look at what it is doing:

A table scan on `user_activity`, an indexed lookup of the `user_profile_id_int` using the PRIMARY KEY of `user_profile`, and an in-place update of the current row in `user_activity`.

The query is hitting two tables and two primary keys, back and forth, on a per-row basis. All steps slow each other down. Thus, you get a longer running query.

### **CAVEAT**

Adding a compound index on `user_profile` should speed things up:

```
ALTER TABLE user_profile ADD INDEX (user_profile_id,user_profile_id_int);
```

Comment: Thanx man, but how is this one better?

Comment: I get error with the second one:
UPDATE `user_activity` ac INNER `user_profile` pr ON ac.user_profile1_id = pr.user_profile_id SET ac.user_profile1_id_int = pr.user_profile_id_int;

Comment: I forgot the word JOIN after the word INNER. I just updated it. Try Again !!!

Comment: Thanx, I ran the query. I will post the result ;)

Comment: WOW ! I don't believe it ! 33 min 18 sec !!!! Thanx man ! Best DBA ever !

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try adding `LIMIT` to your update (and modify a bit `WHERE` to filter out already changed records). If you do, for instance, `LIMIT 100`, it won't take 1 day. Surely, if you want to change all the records, you will have to write a script that executes `UPDATE` until number of updated rows is 0, but it won't block the whole table.

Comment: Thanx, But you know, I want to do this update and learn more about the queries. Because in the future I have to work with large datasets so I think its important for me to understand more about these.

Comment: Some DML statements will take long(or comparatively long). If you update all records in 100GB table, you shouldn't expect it to happen in 1 second. In your case having an index on 2 `user_profile` fields (`user_profile.user_profile_id, user_profile.user_profile_id_int`) may improve your update query performance , but creating such an index may also take long time.

Comment: I did the indexing before and it took long time. But the join solution which RolandoMySQLDBA said is great. It was done in 30 mins !